# Unable to load file from classpath with IntellijIdea runner

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, classpath

I am starting application from intellij idea and provide classpath of module where from application main class is. I see in console that module xxx\classes folder is added to classpath. Then when I try to read xml file that lays in root of classpath I can not find it. 
I tryed to read like this

```
Bootstrap.class.getResource("context.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I have to add / to file name.

```
Bootstrap.class.getResource("/context.xml")
```